# Android project:Google map does not appear

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I just started android programming

when I run the project the map does not appear even logcat not signal any error
I use Google APIs (Google Inc.) emulator level 17
here is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
        }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyBndxO_rEE8zDAulUH7DsCCpKEs2Nxot5I" />

</LinearLayout>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.macarte"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
    </permission>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
    </permission>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </permission>
 <uses-permission android:name=".MaCarte.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.macarte.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details, like code, that would help the community answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You should use  SupportMapFragment or MapFragment

Comment: I have another project where I use MapFragment but it's still the same problem the map does not appear

Comment: Do you see a grid or the map just doesn't load? If you see the grid is likely that your key is not right

Comment: Yes I see the grid and buttons guidance

Comment: I verified my SHA1 key in eclipse Window-> Preferences-> Android-> Build and I even generated a new key on Google APIs Console, but it does not work

Comment: Ok I see what is happening. You are using the <permission> attribute instead of using <uses-permission>. Also you should write the complete package name here <uses-permission android:name=".MaCarte.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />. Also you are missing this <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>. The <permission> attribute is correct here. Make sure you replace com.example.mapdemo with your package name